# Adventures of the riddle (solve the riddle)

Tags: riddle, lateral-thinking, poetry

> In sports and games, I'm in the play,
> Bouncing and spinning, throughout the day.
> From basketball to tennis, I'm found,
> A familiar sight, rolling around.
>
> In nature's realm, I bring delight,
> A fruit so juicy, colours so bright.
> From oranges to sunflowers, I'm seen,
> A symbol of beauty, nature's serene.
>
> Tick-tock, tick-tock, I never rest,
> Counting time, I am the best.
> With hands that move, in a circular way,
> Marking the hours, night and day.
>
> In the night sky, a shining light,
> A celestial body, glowing so bright.
> From planets to moons, I'm above,
> A heavenly wonder, filled with love.

What am I?

Comment: Is the answer a single word? If so, the [[tag:word]] tag applies.

Comment: @bobble it's not exactly a single word

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe a circle? Because it is in all ball games, it is the shape of oranges and sunflowers, its the shape of a clock and planets?

Comment: I thought about "round shape" but circle is also correct. You guessed it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is

> sunlight, because it is everything, in nature's realm it brings life, it never rests, it marks hours and the night, and gives light and the moon.

Comment: Sunlight doesn't quite spin last time I checked :D